# Install packages offline on 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, apt, dpkg

I need to install several packages, including `apache2`, on a Ubuntu 16.04.1 machine with no internet connection.  An interesting feature of `apache2` is that it has dependencies with dependencies with dependencies.  Solutions need to recurse.

On a machine *with* an internet connection, I can successfully use

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

On earlier versions of Ubuntu, I could successfully use `apt-get install <package>` which would populate `/var/cache/apt` with deb files.  I would then copy these onto the non-connected machine and run `apt-get install <package>` there.

On 16.04, no debs appear in `/var/cache/apt`.

I have tried:

```
apt-get --print-uris --yes install [package] | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 | wget -i -
```

...but this only goes one level deep.

```
for i in $(apt-cache depends [package] | grep -E 'Depends|Recommends|Suggests' \
| cut -d ':' -f 2,3 | sed -e s/'<'/''/ -e s/'>'/''/); \
do sudo apt-get download $i 2>>errors.txt; done
```

...but this missed things out.  It omits the top level, which I could fix using the first method, but it also misses other dependencies further down which I don't understand and don't have a workaround for.

```
APTonCD
```

...but it doesn't list any packages on 16.04 - presumably because there are none in the cache.

```
Keryx
```

...hasn't been updated in four years, as far as I can tell, so I haven't bothered trying.

Is there a proper way of doing this, please?

A solution which works *regardless of whether the connected system already has the package in question* would be preferred over one which doesn't.

---

Please be careful before flagging this as a duplicate.  So far all solutions I've found for Ubuntu 14.04 and earlier do *not* work.

Comment: On my 16.04 I get packages to `/var/cache/apt/archives`. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Mark, give Keryx another look. I just got some time to revive the project and released version 0.92.5.

Answer (score 0):

The packages appear in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.